# Message if query result is empty flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard with reactive tables. Users can select dates and expect results but, if my query is empty, how can explain the user no data is available? how can I exit from that code?

````
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
dataset <- eventReactive(input$button_execute, {
  date_start <- input$input_date_start
  date_end <- input$input_date_end
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  query <- "SELECT * FROM mytable"
  conection <- dbConnect(drv, 
                       dbname = "xxx", 
                       host = "xxx",
                       user = "xxx",
                       password = "xxx",
                       port = 9999)
  rs <- dbSendQuery(conection, query)
  fetched <- dbFetch(rs)
  fetched <- fetched %>% mutate(colnew = sum(colmoney)) 
  dbDisconnect(conection)
})
```
````

I tried the following:

```
if(nrow(fetched) != 0) then {
   # execute the mutate 
} else { 
   # say no data
}
```

My question is: is there a way to exit with a message in flexdashboard and avoid render the reactive tables?

Comment: For anything that relies on `dataset()`, perhaps add to that dependent block: `validate(need(NROW(dataset()) > 0), "no data found")`. See [`?shiny::validate`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/validate.html).

Comment: But I think the point is that each *dependent* block can handle this differently (either some message or just a big "0" (zero)).

Comment: Hello @r2evans, as per your comments (and documentation link) the function `validate` works for reactive objects like renderPlot. Just a question, isn't it possible to do it inside the eventReactive? If there is no data, does shiny have a handler to exit the eventReactive?

Comment: Well, if you add `req(NROW(fetched)>0)` after `dbDisconnect`, then this will prevent any dependent reactive blocks from firing, but it does not allow the ability to show a message to the user. Your choice: block all in one place and have no message to the user; or block in all other places and provide a message to the user.

Comment: Hello @r2evans, thank you very much for the answer and time, it made me look for `req` function and I found other way to do the task. Hope you have a great day.